# HTTP Error 404.2 - Not Found while downloading .DLL files from web server

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5, isapi

I have deployed the `ASP.NET applications` in the `IIS 7.5` under the application pool `Classic .NET AppPool`.

[image]

Now, One of the application has the `functionality to download the .dll files` from the server to the client machine .

So, I added the extension `.dll(application/x-msdownload) to the MIME types` and also checked the `RequestFiltering` whether it denies .dll extension.

[image]

But, it throws the error while downloading the .dll file from the browser.

[image]

What are the settings to be made in `IIS` to download the .DLL files through web server?